# Import excel into Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, excel-import

i need to import the data from excel files in Informatica. I have created a ODBC connection to bring this in as a source. But I need to define a 'name' in the excel to consider that as a table to import. Is there any way where I can import the excel without defining a name in the excel i.e. only by referring the file name of excel. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. You can use Excel as a source only with a named range.